# onclick attribute when moving .aspx files

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

```
<input type="button" class="write_button" value="Write" onclick = "window.open('Write.aspx','Write');"/>
```

Currently I'm using `window.open` to test whether button moves to directed `.aspx` file. But one thing '`window.open`' offers is that it opens up new window. I searched some related options to `onclick`, and open but I am not sure how can I move to different `.aspx` files uploading on existing page.

Comment: You want to open the new page(new.aspx) on same page(old.aspx) on some click event on old.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this :-

```
window.open("Write.aspx","_self")
```

or :-

```
location.href = "Write.aspx";
```